# Deploying Silverlight RIA The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: ria

I've installed RIA Server, set the relevant DLL's to "copy local = true" but whenever my application tries to access my service/db I get:

Load operation failed for query 'GetWeatherDatas'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

I deployed by copying the xap file and the test page from Visual Studio.

Fiddler reports a 404 error

GET /TheWeatherProjectv2-Web-WeatherDataService.svc/binary/GetWeatherDatas?$orderby=it.date_recorded%2bdesc&$take=10080

Are there application settings I need to add to IIS or change something in my web config?

The machine is Windows 7 pro, running IIS 7.5, I'm hosting the application on my own machine.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this problem by using 'publish' via Visual Studio 2012, I also had to add an IISAPPPOOL\DefaultAppPool account in my SQL Server database